# How to understand the following QGIS SQL expression

Tags: qgis, sql

In a QGIS Layer I encountered the following SQL expression and I'm wondering what the '#' and '%' symbols are for:

```
'#' + "IDs" + '#'  LIKE '%#' +  to_string( attribute( @atlas_feature ,'ID')) + '#%'
```

The Statement basically means, if the field "IDs" in the layer has the same numbers like the 'ID' field in the current atlas_feature layer, return true.

I don't understand the purpose of the '#' and '%' smybols. Why not simply write

```
"IDs" LIKE to_string( attribute( @atlas_feature ,'ID'))
```

Comment: `%` represents zero or more characters, `re% finds re, red, and representationalism etc.`. `#` represents any single numeric character `1#8 finds 108, 118, 188 etc.`

Comment: I'm not aware of `#` being a single character wildcard in QGIS (expressions, DB Manager SQL, etc).  I can't seem to get it to work. `_`works on the other hand?

Comment: OP, what does your `IDs` field look like? Is it a bunch of numbers delimited with `#` by any chance? (e.g. `1#2#3`)

Comment: @she_weeds they are a bunch of numbers, some are empty, maybe among the empty ones there are some 'spaces'

Comment: I see now. The `#` character is a numeric wildcard character in MS Access (thanks again Access for being special and weird). I don't think that would work in QGIS. If the `IDs` values were a series of numbers delimited by `#`, then that expression actually makes sense - if your atlas feature `ID` is 1 then the expression matches `1#2#3`, `2#1#3`, `3#2#1` but not e.g. `2#11#3` - but not otherwise.

Comment: Ok I get it now. Thanks for the help you two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%` is special character (only in **second** argument to LIKE expression) substituting for zero or more arbitrary characters.

`#` has no special meaning in SQL `LIKE` expressions in most databases.

The names used here suggest this expression uses it as its own special character. Probably `attribute( @atlas_feature ,'ID')` is a single ID, and column `IDs` is probably a list of IDs separated by `#`. The query checks that `ID` is in `IDs` list.

If it compared strings without `#`, the query would mistakenly find `ID` = `1` in list `111#222`. By surrounding it with `#`, it makes sure only full IDs are compared. In example above, the condition would be `'#111#222#' LIKE '%#1#%'` and would not match. But if `ID` was 111, the condition would be be `'#111#222#' LIKE '%#111#%'` and this does match.